# LTLIBRARIES: mv *.Tpo *.Plo, but the former doesn't exist and the latter already does

Tags: macos, autotools, automake, libtool

I'm doing a pretty straight-forward conversion of an existing library (libtcod) to Autotools (for OS X happiness).  Unfortunately, when I switch my `Makefile.am`'s `lib_LIBRARIES` rule to `lib_LTLIBRARIES`, the build goes from successful to un.  Excerpt from the output below:

```
Making all in .
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all-am'.
Making all in src
/bin/sh ../libtool --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -g -O2 -MT bresenham_c.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/bresenham_c.Tpo -c -o bresenham_c.lo bresenham_c.c
mv -f .deps/bresenham_c.Tpo .deps/bresenham_c.Plo
mv: rename .deps/bresenham_c.Tpo to .deps/bresenham_c.Plo: No such file or directory
make[1]: *** [bresenham_c.lo] Error 1
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

`src/Makefile.am` looks like this:

```
lib_LTLIBRARIES = libtcod.la
libtcod_la_SOURCES = bresenham_c.c bresenham3_c.c bsp_c.c color_c.c ...
```

`src/.deps` contains:

```
$ ls src/.deps/
bresenham_c.Plo bresenham_c.Po ...
```

Am I making an obvious mistake here, or should this work?

Answer (score 12):

Yes, I'm making an obvious mistake.  I needed to run `autoreconf -i` to create a non-empty `ltmain.sh` script; the existing one made `../libtool` here a no-op.

Comment: I have been bashing my head against this this same problem for some time.  My program complied great, untill I tried it on openSUSE12.1.  This fixed me.

Comment: what are .Tpo and .Plo, by the way ? and how do `autoreconf -i` help fixing issues related to them ? and why doesn't this appear anywhere in the README or INSTALL documentation of projects depending on automake ?

Comment: I have no idea what any of this is, but it solved my problem in trying to compile rxp-1.5.0, as part of the SPEC tools in CPU2006-1.2 on ARM. So thank you for that.